# Can't receive silent remote notification. But can received after restart iphone

Tags: ios, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I had set up silent remote notification in my app. And send valid silent remote notification frequently(per 2 minutes) from my own server. It worked well. My app can received silent push notification in background, sometimes will lost few, it's acceptable for me.

But, after update Beta version from testflight, app can't receive silent remote notification anymore. I checked server process, it worked normally, all silent remote notifications were sent to APNs. And apple token for this app didn't change. I try to kill&reopen app. Still can't received.

So, i restarted iphone. Then silent remote notification can be received normally and frequently.

I know APNs will control the silent remote notification. But the behavior after restart iphone was so different. Does anyone know the reason? Or It's a bug of iOS?

Thanks,
Martin